# Bootstrapping of Django 1.7 application to deploy on OpenShift

Tags: python, django, openshift

I want to deploy Django 1.7 application on openshift.
I've tried the steps given at
[Deploying a local django app using openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871381/deploying-a-local-django-app-using-openshift)
but I'm getting

503 Service Unavailable
No server is available to handle this request.

Error message.

can anyone please tell me the correct way to deploy the  Django 1.7 application on openshift?

wsgi.py (created by Openshift) contains following code

`

```
 import os

 virtenv = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR'] + '/virtenv/'
 virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
 try:
     execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
 except IOError:
     pass
 # 
 #
 # IMPORTANT: Put any additional includes below this line.  If placed above this
 # line, it's possible required libraries won't be in your searchable path
 #
 from social.wsgi import application
```

`
the directory structure is

```
.
|-- coleccioneselcomercio
|   |-- static
|   `-- templates
|-- manage.py
|-- network
|   |-- admin.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- static
|   |   `-- network
|   |       `-- favicon.ico
|   |-- templates
|   |   `-- network
|   |       |-- index.html
|   |       |-- Login.html
|   |       `-- Signup.html
|   |-- tests.py
|   `-- views.py
|-- requirements.txt
|-- setup.py
|-- social
|   |-- app_Global.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   `-- wsgi.py
|-- wsgi
|   `-- static
`-- wsgi.py
```

the social/wsgi.py is the default wsgi.py created by django-admin
it contains

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "social.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

another thing I want to ask is what does this code in wsgi.py created by openshift does and whether it should be kept in the wsgi.py or i should comment it out?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    httpd = make_server('localhost', 8051, application)
    # Wait for a single request, serve it and quit.
    httpd.handle_request()
```

Comment: You may need to post some of your source code for us to help!

Comment: I've edited the post. could u please help me? please let me know if any other code i need to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not found the correct and clear instructions for bootstrapping and settings of django application for Openshift.

from these two links

[Deploying a local django app using openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871381/deploying-a-local-django-app-using-openshift)

and

https://github.com/jfmatth/openshift-django17

I figured out the correct directory structure and settings required to deploy Django1.7 application on Openshift.

I have written this script to bootstrap the Django application for Openshift

https://github.com/girish946/Power-Django-Openshift

now it works fine for me.