# Export local Django website to Open Shift

Tags: django, hosting, web-hosting

Recently I created a website in Python with a Django framework on a local server (MySQL). ([background information](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/python-from-scratch-create-a-dynamic-website--net-22787)) Now my website is finished, (html, css and jQuery are working great) I want to bring it to an online host to run it from there and in the very end get the website online on some domainname.

I found Open Shift for Python and Django support, I ran through the '[Getting Started](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-osx.html)'-tutorial: installing client tools, cloned a `git`-repository, created an application Django with a cartridge Python or vice versa and it works! Or at least a new folder appeared in Finder with the name Django (I believe this is the name of my project) and 'cloned' files of my local framework (`__init__.py`, `settings.py`, `urls.py` and `wsgi.py`).

Now I don't know how to get my `.css`, `.html` and `.js` files to the webhost. I think they have to be imported in the online Django framework, by `git`-commands? But if so, how will the `static_files` (only `.css`, `.html` and `.js`) be linked to each other?

**Local Project Directory Structure:**

```
PyhtonWeb/
+---wget-1.15
+---WebsiteName/
|   +----manage.py
|   +----JFP/    (local, website is inhere)
|        +----__init__.py and .pyc
|        +----settings.py and .pyc
|        +----urls.py and .pyc
|        +----wsgi.py and .pyc
|        +----blog/
|             +----__init__.py and .pyc
|             +----admin.py and .pyc
|             +----models.py and .pyc
|             +----tests.py
|             +----views.py and .pyc
|             +----migrations/
|                  +----__init__.py and .pyc
|                  +----0001_initial.py and .pyc
|             +----templates/
|                  +----Site.py
|                  +----staticfiles/
|                       +----main.css
|                       +----site.py
|                       +----apps.js
|                  +----static_root/
|                       +----main.css
|                       +----site.py
|                       +----apps.js
|                       +----admin/
|                            +----css/
|                            +----img/
|                            +----cs/
|   +----django/    (created on Open Shift) (git-repository)
|        +----requirements.txt
|        +----setup.py
|        +----wsgi.py
|        +----JFP/
|             +----manage.py
|             +----JFP/
|                  +----__init__.py
|                  +----settings.py
|                  +----urls.py
|                  +----wsgi.py
```

It is very good possible I am using some terminology in the wrong way or context, I am just a beginner. ;-) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add your project directory structure, both on your local server and on open shift?

Comment: Done! It is exactly like this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871381/deploying-a-local-django-app-using-openshift