# Django on Openshift - 500 Internal Server Error - error in wsgi.py

Tags: python, django, openshift

I tried to deploy my django app on the OpenShift, but somesthing going wrong, and I dont't know how to solve this problem.

The result from `rhc tail -a myproject`:
(and the site page show 500 Internal Server Error)

```
[Sat Feb 27 07:23:32 2016] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Sat Feb 27 07:23:32 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Feb 27 07:23:32 2016] [notice] Digest: done
[Sat Feb 27 07:23:32 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/3.3.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 27 07:25:08 2016] [error] [client 127.5.163.1] mod_wsgi (pid=506177): Target WSGI script '/var/lib/openshift/56d067420c1e664f0e0000da/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi.py' can
not be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Feb 27 07:25:08 2016] [error] [client 127.5.163.1] mod_wsgi (pid=506177): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/lib/openshift/56d067420c1e664f0e0000da/app-root/ru
ntime/repo/wsgi.py'.
[Sat Feb 27 07:25:08 2016] [error] [client 127.5.163.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Feb 27 07:25:08 2016] [error] [client 127.5.163.1]   File "/var/lib/openshift/56d067420c1e664f0e0000da/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi.py", line 10, in <module>
[Sat Feb 27 07:25:08 2016] [error] [client 127.5.163.1]     from myblog.wsgi import application
[Sat Feb 27 07:25:08 2016] [error] [client 127.5.163.1]   File "/var/lib/openshift/56d067420c1e664f0e0000da/app-root/runtime/repo/myblog/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Sat Feb 27 07:25:08 2016] [error] [client 127.5.163.1]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Sat Feb 27 07:25:08 2016] [error] [client 127.5.163.1]   File "/var/lib/openshift/56d067420c1e664f0e0000da/python/virtenv/venv/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py
", line 2, in <module>
[Sat Feb 27 07:25:08 2016] [error] [client 127.5.163.1]     from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
[Sat Feb 27 07:25:08 2016] [error] [client 127.5.163.1]   File "/var/lib/openshift/56d067420c1e664f0e0000da/python/virtenv/venv/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/handler
s/wsgi.py", line 10, in <module>
[Sat Feb 27 07:25:08 2016] [error] [client 127.5.163.1]     from django import http
[Sat Feb 27 07:25:08 2016] [error] [client 127.5.163.1]   File "/var/lib/openshift/56d067420c1e664f0e0000da/python/virtenv/venv/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/django/http/__init_
_.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sat Feb 27 07:25:08 2016] [error] [client 127.5.163.1]     from django.http.request import (
[Sat Feb 27 07:25:08 2016] [error] [client 127.5.163.1]   File "/var/lib/openshift/56d067420c1e664f0e0000da/python/virtenv/venv/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/django/http/request
.py", line 10, in <module>
[Sat Feb 27 07:25:08 2016] [error] [client 127.5.163.1]     from django.core import signing
[Sat Feb 27 07:25:08 2016] [error] [client 127.5.163.1]   File "/var/lib/openshift/56d067420c1e664f0e0000da/python/virtenv/venv/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/signing
.py", line 51, in <module>
[Sat Feb 27 07:25:08 2016] [error] [client 127.5.163.1]     from django.utils.module_loading import import_string
[Sat Feb 27 07:25:08 2016] [error] [client 127.5.163.1]   File "/var/lib/openshift/56d067420c1e664f0e0000da/python/virtenv/venv/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/django/utils/module
_loading.py", line 67, in <module>
[Sat Feb 27 07:25:08 2016] [error] [client 127.5.163.1]     from importlib.util import find_spec as importlib_find
[Sat Feb 27 07:25:08 2016] [error] [client 127.5.163.1] ImportError: cannot import name find_spec
1.194.187.34 - - [27/Feb/2016:07:25:08 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 618 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safa
ri/537.36"
```

It's my first time to deploy my app at OpenShift, a PaaS platform.
Before that, I only deploy it successfully on my CVM with centos(python3.5, django 1.9.2).

My files put like this:

```
myproject/
+---wsgi/
|   +---static/
|       +---.gitkeep
+---wsgi.py
+---setup.py
+---.openshift/ 
+---requirements.txt
+---myblog/
|   +----__init__.py
|   +----urls.py
|   +----settings.py
|   +----wsgi.py
+---+blog/
    +----__init__.py
    +----models.py
    +----views.py
    +----tests.py
    +----migrations
         +---__init__.py
```

myproject/wsgi.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
virtenv = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR'] + '/virtenv/'
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
try:
    exec(compile(open(virtualenv, 'rb').read(), virtualenv, 'exec'), dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:
    pass

from myblog.wsgi import application
```

myproject/myblog/wsgi.py:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myblog.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

My Django version is latest 1.9.2, python 3.3 is provided by openshift.

Thank you for watching my problem and help me figure out.

Comment: my reference resources:[Deploying a local django app using openshift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871381/deploying-a-local-django-app-using-openshift) and [Django-OpenShift-1.8 on Github](https://github.com/Gpzim98/Django-OpenShift-1.8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django 1.9 only [supports Python 3.4 or higher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#python-compatibility). Your specific error is caused by the call to `find_spec` which was [added in Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.find_spec).

You can either downgrade to Django 1.8 or choose another PaaS provider which supports Python 3.4.