# Deploying on Openshift

Tags: django, openshift, django-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my project on Openshift.
I tried some tutorials but none worked.
So I'm asking if you have your own "procedure" or some working (really working) tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

This is duplicate. Well I think most of the tutorials work, but you need to make a simple changes to your code depending on Django version you are using, folder structure etc. Here is a nice [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871381/deploying-a-local-django-app-using-openshift).
If you have errors even after applying all step, you need to check logs on OpenShift and fix them. Learning to read OpenShift logs is really crucial. Either use `rhc tail app_name` or login to you app and read logs in `app-root/logs/` directory.
Prepared [django app for OpenShift](https://github.com/openshift/django-example) might be also a good choice.
Setting up Django in OpenShift is not that easy, but you will learn how it works and it is really useful later as well(installing apps, setting up MEDIA and STATIC url, ...).