# Configure WSGI with Django on OpenShift

Tags: python, django, openshift, wsgi, django-1.8

I tried to configure WSGI with **wsgi.py** in my project folder

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR']))

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'

virtenv = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR'] + 'python/virtenv/'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = os.path.join(virtenv, 'lib/python2.7/site-packages')

virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
try:
    execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:
    pass
#
# IMPORTANT: Put any additional includes below this line.  If placed above this
# line, it's possible required libraries won't be in your searchable path
#

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

but I have **Internal Server Error 500**

```
[Wed Jun 08 16:42:46 2016] [error] [client 127.9.155.129] ImportError: No module named project.settings
```

and I have this module available in my projet.

I tried some help like :

- http://www.appsembler.com/blog/django-deployment-using-openshift/
- [How to configure Django on OpenShift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688819/how-to-configure-django-on-openshift)

Can you help my to launch my app on OpenShift

Thanks

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688819/how-to-configure-django-on-openshift) question might help you.

Comment: Thanks @Natsukane for the link but I refered already this link in my post. And the answer does not solve my issue

Comment: My bad, I didn't check that link and assumed it linked to another website instead of SO. In any case, the code in your example and that link is different - did you get the same error when testing that solution? Also, please include the code from your setup.py in your question.

Comment: Also include what is the value for os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'] and the full path for the project.settings. It seems like project.settings is not available under the sys path by the time it is getting evaluated.

Comment: @Natsukane you want the setup.py under project folder ?

Comment: @PraveenYalagandula how do you include the full path of my project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had on the top of **wsgi.py**

```
os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR'], 'app-root/repo')
```

and I didn't have this error !
And I also put all my code under folder which have the name of my project in order to match

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'
```